# Динамические миграции Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Есть проект в котором регистрируется пользователь.
При успешной регистрации для пользователя создается отдельная база данных mysql с таблицами на сервере.
Так как я имею дело с Yii2 фреймворком мне пока что не ясно как это делать.
На данный момент я имею 25 миграций для новой базы данных пользователя.
Но чтобы не делать это каждый раз при регистрации пользователя вручную, хочу автоматизировать этот процесс.

**Вопрос:** при успешной регистрации пользователя я могу узнать имя новой базы данных.
Как настроить миграции так, чтобы зная имя базы данных накатить туда определенные миграции?

Comment: Я практически уверен, что на самом деле вам не нужно создавать новую базу данных

Comment: @Etki  согласен. если конечно не пилитца система для каждого нового юзера свой магазин к примеру конструктор какой либо. где можно с легкостью перенести базы на разные сервера. ну да все таки я думаю не тот это случай.

Comment: crm система арендной платы.

Comment: @Mr.Music, миграция это инструмент для удобного обмена изменениями в базе между разработчиками, а вам нужно просто сделать манипуляции с mysql, так и делайте их там, где обычно делают, в `Controller'e` в `Action`, который у вас отвечает за регистрацию пользователя.

Answer (score 3):

Если в классах миграций в методе `init()` не определяется жестко какая-то конкретная база, то, вызывая комманду `migrate`, Вы можете указать опцию `--db`, в которой можете указать на компонент подключения к нужной базе.

Например: `yii migrate --db=db2` - применит миграции к базе данных `db2`.

Это не сработает, если в методе `init()` задана конкретная база. Например:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->db = 'db3';
    parent::init();
}
```

В Вашем случае, я так понимаю, нужно запустить миграции сразу же после успешной регистрации. Про то, как запустить комманду миграций из приложения почитайте тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983169/how-to-handle-yii2-migrations-on-hosts-without-console-access, и тут: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60000-run-migrate-command-in-a-function-in-yii2/.

И вот, что Вам нужно будет сделать (*исхожу из того, что Вы ознакомились с приведенными ссылками и что это за кусок кода и куда его вставлять Вам уже понятно*):

```
new \yii\console\Application([
    'id'            => 'Command runner',
    'basePath'      => '@app',
    'components'    => [
        'db' => ... /* тут нужно будет зарегистрировать компонент подключения 
к только что созданной базе данных. Зная ее имя, с этим не должно возникнуть трудностей */

    ],
]);
```